# Save As - "filename & date from cell", in 20160127 format

Tags: excel, vba

so i've been looking here and googling for quite a bit, and i can find some good tips on how to code this, but nothing on the how to keep the dateformat.

I want to save a file i've opened in the routine, but with the date in this particular format, 20160127 (as it is in the source-cell) added to the filename.

Right now, the value in Fname gets stored as 01/27/2016, not in its current format.

Fname = [cellwithdate]

Daily.SaveAs ("D:\Docs\vba\Daily Summary_US_ " & Fname & ".xlsx")

Current filename is "Daily Summary_US_.xlsx". Can i just add Fname to it like so? And how do i keep it in its correct format?

cheers.

Comment: If not get the date from cell, it would be like **Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd_hhmm")**, hope this help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or You can use:

```
Fname = [cellwithdate].Text
```

to keep the cell's original format (as it is in the source-cell).

Answer (score 5):

You can use **Format** to achieve your goal:

```
Dim Fname As String

Fname = Format([cellwithdate], "yyyyMMdd")

Daily.SaveAs ("D:\Docs\vba\Daily Summary_US_ " & Fname & ".xlsx")
```

For getting the current date and time with format:

```
Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd_hhmmss")
```

MSDN with the detail explanation 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx

For saving the file in **SaveAs**, it is better to state the file format as:

```
Daily.SaveAs "D:\Docs\vba\Daily Summary_US_ " & Fname & ".xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx

Comment: Was hoping you'd put the comment as an answer.  Might also be useful to add the file format to the save command `Daily.SaveAs "D:\Docs\vba\Daily Summary_US_ " & Fname & ".xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook`.    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx.

Comment: i have date saved in the cell as custom format "yyyy-mm-dd" and neither of these options work on my file. Works fine with current date though. Is there a change in syntax or option that would work with custom date?